# The efficiency of Spark/Pyspark Dataframe join multiple times

Tags: performance, dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a DataFrame A, and I need to use serval columns in A to generate a new feature and then join it back to A. If I generate more than 1 features in this way, this time cost by Dataframe.join increasing. Just like:

```py
for i in range(10):
   starttime = time.time()
   A = A.join(some_pd_udf(A.select(...)))
   costtime = time.time() - startttime
```

costtime is exponential growth. I know spark is lazy, and the real computation of the data has not been trigged.

However, If I used DataFrame.withColumn to add a new column, this phenomenon is gone. Just like:

```py
for i in range(10):
   A = A.with(some_pd_udf(A.select(...)))

starttime = time.time()
A = A.with(some_pd_udf(A.select(...)))
costtime = time.time() - startttime
```

In this case, costtime is very small. But sometimes, I have to use join the add a new column.

Can anyone explain what is behind it and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you check how many partitions are used by each new DataFrame in that loop?

Comment: I have checked it, the partition number is increased quit a lot (36->200) when I use join function. So why is this so?

Comment: it's a hard-coded default that lurks in the shadows and tries to make beginner's life miserable >> http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/dynamic-spark-shuffle-partitions/ for example

Comment: There are also dark tales about the query optimizer getting mad after too many JOINs; sometimes, checkpointing to disk may bring it back from its "lazyness"-induced madness

Comment: So how can I solve it? Could you give me some code to follow? Thank you very much!
By the way, I have tried to dynamically set n_partition to 36 in this code, But it does not help.

Comment: If I join all the generated features at last,  the cost time is reduced to seconds. However, I may have to do the same process again, but the time cost is increased to a very big level again If I use the dataframe generated from the previous process. I think it can be solved by save and resotore a new DataFrame, but it is not a good solution. I have tried "cache" "persist", they do not help.